# Pandas data type catch errors while converting without using Try Except

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change the data type of a column from object to date in pandas dataframe. I cannot control the data type with dtypes because both the string(text) and date data are of object type. (I shouldn't use Try Except). Can I find out if the selected column contains string values ​​without using Try Except?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas's [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) has an `errors` argument. You can set it to `'coerce'`, for instance, to turn bad dates into `NaT`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'t': ['20200101', '2020-01-01', 'foobar', '2020-01-01T12:17:00.333']})
pd.to_datetime(df['t'], errors='coerce')

# out:
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
1   2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
2                       NaT
3   2020-01-01 12:17:00.333
Name: t, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I knew this parameter. I wanted no convert in that column if there is a string value, so I wanted to check it. Thank you for the answer I can use that too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to convert `object` to `datetime`

```
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I knew this parameter. I wanted no convert in that column if there is a string value, so I wanted to check it. Thank you for the answer I can use that too.